# Ember-Data Table from 2 sources with relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, relationship

I think ember (data) is great, but I can't get my head around on how to create a html table which lists the company name and the person. What I'd like to get is:

**Company          Name**
Microsoft                  Steve Ballmer
Microsoft                  Bill Gates

Apple                            Steve Jobs

What i get is:

**Company          Name**
Microsoft                            Steve Ballmer,Bill Gates
Apple                                      Steve Jobs

I really would appreciate any help with this.

Here is jsbin:http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EnOqUxe/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set up two each loops, the first iterating the companies, the second iterating the people within the company outside the table row loop.

```
{{#each company in model}}
   {{#each person in company.people}}
   <tr>
      <td>{{ company.name }}</td>
      <td> {{ person.name }}</td>
   </tr>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EnOqUxe/9/edit